# Join two tables based on column condtion

Tags: sql, join

In MS SQL Server, there are two tables, 'T1', and 'T2', having a common field 'ID (PK)', where ID is unique but for the same ID record, the Date in T1 and T2 could be different, and the content of ABC or DEF could also be different  E.g:

```
----------
T1:
----------
ID   Date     A     B      C
----------
55   12/1/17  Jim  Smith  Male
77   12/2/17  Jim  Green  Male
99   10/3/17  Kate Lee    Male

T2:
----------
ID   Date       D    E     F
----------
55   12/1/17  Jim  Smith  Male
77   10/2/16  James  Jr   Male
99   12/25/17 Kathy  Lee  Male
```

I would like to have a some form of a joined table based on the ID and choosing either ABC or DEF depending on the latest date, in this case ,I would like to have

```
----------
ID   Date     join1| join2 | join3
----------
55   12/1/17  Jim  Smith  Male
77   12/2/17  Jim  Green  Male
99   12/25/17 Kathy Lee   Male
```

Is that possible?

What I have come up with so far, is kinda of tedious: I did a full outer join firstly:

```
select * from T1 full outer join  T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

to have the following:

---

```
ID   Date     A     B      C     Date2     D       E       F
----------
55   12/1/17  Jim  Smith  Male   12/1/17  Jim    Smith   Male
77   12/2/17  Jim  Green  Male   10/2/16  James   Jr     Male
99   10/3/17  Kate Lee    Male   12/25/17 Kathy   Lee    Male
```

Then I attempted to use `case when then else` to select ABC or DEF fields, which looks quite ugly and I am worried about the performance.

```
select T1.ID, 
        case when T1.Date > T2.Date then T1.Date else T2.Date END as Date 
        case when T1.Date > T2.Date then T1.A else T2.D END as Join1
        case when T1.Date > T2.Date then T1.B else T2.E END as Joni2
        case when T1.Date > T2.Date then T1.C else T2.F END as Join3
from RESULT_TABLE
```

Is that possible to do something like the following:

```
    select T1.ID,
           case when T1.Date > T2.Date then 
                T1.Date, T1.A as Join1, T1.B as Join2, T1.C as Join3
           else
                T2.Date, T2.D as Join1 , T2.E as Join2, T2.F as Join3
           END 
from RESULT_TABLE
```

Comment: Although the data shouldn't shape the SQL - can u provide more data?? :)

Comment: What engine (DB2, mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  I'd use a union, cte and a row_number() over partition by... to select the details of the record with the most recent date.

Comment: @xQbert could you elaborate more? I am using SQL Server by the way.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `case`:

```
select t1.id,
       (case when t1.date >= t2.date then t1.date else t2.date end) as date,
       (case when t1.date >= t2.date then t1.a else t2.a end) as a,
       (case when t1.date >= t2.date then t1.b else t2.a end) as b,
       (case when t1.date >= t2.date then t1.c else t2.a end) as c
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

If you don't like all the `case` expressions, you can do:

```
select t1.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date >= t2.date
union all
select t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date < t2.date;
```

Note:  You might want to list the columns out rather than using `select *`.  This version assumes that the two tables have exactly the same columns, in the same order, with compatible types.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not expect answers on SO get back so fast! 
I guess the second solution with union does not fit into my case, because the majority of fields are different in my tables except ID and Date; so I have to use "case when" probably. However, I have around 40 fields need to "case when",  so similarily to what I tried to express in my original post -- is that possible to group "Case when then else"? So that checking the conditional only has to be done once, instead of 40 times for each field,  If not, would there be any performance issue if I create a VIEW using this query?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

```
Select t1.Id, 
  case when t1.Date > t2.Date then t1.Date else t2.Date end date,
  case when t1.Date > t2.Date then t1.A else t2.D end AD,
  case when t1.Date > t2.Date then t1.B else t2.E end BE,
  case when t1.Date > t2.Date then t1.C else t2.F end CF

From T1 join T2 on t2.Id = t1.Id
```

Comment: would there be too much performance hit if I have many such fields as ABC or DEF, say 40 fields? Is that possible to do conditional only once?

Comment: Query Optimizer should take care of that for you. Use show plan to see. Plus, once query reads row from disk, it is in memory, and does not have to be reread from disk again. Disk reads are 1000s of times more expensive than memory access, so, basically, don't worry about it.